# Use flex direction column in flex grow container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a `div` to have `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `flex: 1`. But for some reason the content of that `div` gets resized.

Using `display: block` does not resize the content.

```css
 body {
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    header {
      height: 2em;
      background: blue;
    }

    main {
      background: yellow;
      flex: 1;
      overflow-y: auto;
      /* Why display: flex resizes the articles */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      /* If you use display: block its working (uncomment to test)*/
      /* display: block; */
    }

    article {
      height: 15em;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 1em;
    }

    footer {
      background: green;
      height: 3em;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <header></header>
      <main>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
      </main>
      <footer></footer>
    </body>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdewKJ

Comment: You need to add `flex-shrink: 0;` to your `article` rule. And the reason is that as they doesn't have any content, and the default `flex-shrink` is `1` (allow to shrink), they will shrink-to-fit, down to their content size (which is none at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below code in your CSS:

```
article {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```